# Copy or clone persistent volume using openshift origin

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, persistent-storage

I have an openshift origin deployment that has a few NFS mounted volumes.  I'd like to be able to clone those volumes so i can mount them to other pods and give those other pods write access to that volume without affecting the original volume's data.  I don't see that documented clearly anywhere - do people have any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

OpenShift doesn't provide any specific features which will help you with doing that.

You have a few options.

On the NFS server, identify the location of the source volume as well as location used by a target volume, and use normal file system copy mechanisms. Only thing you need to be careful of here, is that if the target volume is being used in a different project, then owner uid on files would need to be changed to uid used by other project.

Alternatively, you claim a persistent volume and mount it into the same pod as the source volume and then use `oc rsh` to get into the pod and copy the files between the persistent volumes. Then detach the volume and later mount it into the pod you want to have use it. You are restricted to the volume being used in same project doing it this way.

The only other way is to copy the data out of the persistent volume back to your local computer using `oc rsync` and then copy it back up again into another pod using target volume.

For details on some aspects of copying data around in OpenShift, see the interactive learning scenario on transferring files in and out of containers at:

- https://learn.openshift.com/

Comment: Thanks for the reply - i guess I'm approaching the openshift notion of a volume with the same mindset as one would an AWS EBS volume - e.g. create a volume, take a snapshot create new volume, etc.

Comment: At this time the ability to make use of such functionality of a storage provider through OpenShift simply isn't there. If you have the admin access, then you could do it by working with the storage provider software directly, but you would have to then manually set up the persistent volume definition in OpenShift to use the copy you created.